# Use parent class and get middle part of child class

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, subform

I am working with Joomla's new SubForm code. This allows the user to duplicate a set of inputs and reuse them. Basically a repeatable form.
This form creates the following structure.

```
<div class="subform-repeatable-group">
    <div class="control-group jform_params__content__content0__dc_subheader-cg"></div>
    <div class="control-group jform_params__content__content0__dc_typeofcontent-cg"></div>
    <div class="control-group jform_params__content__content0__dc_toc_image-cg"></div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the SubForm is loaded inside the parent form but Joomla sees it as a independent form. Therefore the normal Show/Hide functions no longer work. So I have to create my own.

## What do I got and what is not good

This is the generated Select:

```
<select id="jform_params_theme_selection" name="jform[params][theme_selection]" class="chzn-done">
  <option value="3dperspective" selected="selected">3D Perspective</option>
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="notheme">Select a theme!</option>
</select>
```

I already got the piece of code that will check if the select value on the parent form is selected.

```
$('#jform_params_theme_selection').bind('change', function (e) {
  if( $('#jform_params_theme_selection').val() == 'notheme') {
  } else if( $('#jform_params_theme_selection').val() == 'default') {
  } else if( $('#jform_params_theme_selection').val() == '3dperspective') {
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

Now I can offcourse for each element add it manually like this:

```
$('[class$="__dc_typeofcontent-cg"]').hide();
```

But there must be a better way.

## What do I want.

1. I want to use the `.hide()` function on every item that has the following letters/symbols in its class `__dc_` and has as `.parents(.subform-repeatable-group)`

## Bit of extra information

1. There is another theme that does not have `__dc_` but is called `__threed_` so I must be able to define the letters/symbols.
2. I already checked if I could use something with X amount of positions from the front or a X amount of positions from the back but that is constantly changing.

## Thanks everyone for helping.

As usual I am going to keep searching and updating this post whenever I get more results.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There are no form controls shown that a change event would work on or that would have a value

Comment: @charlietfl I added that select but I don't believe it is that important. Because the `change function already works` I just need a better way of hiding/showing a vast amount of `control-groups` as they are called in Joomla. And I need this combined with the parent class so it won't hide items on other Tabs. I can't upload all of the code because if I do I am 100% sure the next comment would be to only upload codes that exactly pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use `filter()` something like:

```
  var cGroups = $('.subform-repeatable-group .control-group');

  var hideTheme = '_dc';
  var showTheme = '_threed';

  cGroups.filter(function(){
     return this.className.indexOf(hideTheme )>-1
  }).hide()



  cGroups.filter(function(){
     return this.className.indexOf(showTheme )>-1
  }).show()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tdo9go2q/9/)**</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't this require me to add this for each and every input. Isn't there a way to do it without `_typeofcontent-cg`? There are about a 100+ inputs for only this theme.
Would this work:
$('.subform-repeatable-group [class$="'+theme+'"]').each().hide();

Comment: Not without more html shown as per [mcve]. *"Would this work"* ... did you try it?

Comment: What more HTML do you need? Please tell me as I don't understand what you are missing now?

Comment: I'm only responding to what you are asking. jQuery will hide all matching elements using this, it does `each` internally

Comment: Your answer is already very close I believe only at this point it still requires me to add for each input one line of code. So that will bring a lot of lines of codes and I think it could be simplified with a foreach into it. So foreach `theme` inside `.subform....` do `.hide()`

Comment: Create a demo that includes example of all cases

Comment: Oh my god. That is not possible I can't possibly create a demo with the entire Joomla CMS within it. There are so many factors that render the page it would be a case of not being to see the trees in the woods.

First of all the selects are generated by XML then they get their values from JSON but none of this has anything to do with the question. Even the selectbox has nothing to do with the question.

Basically in a parent div there are a hundred divs with all different classes but all classes have a part `_dc` which is always the same. For each class that have that in that parent. Hide.

Comment: You can certainly copy snippets of html from a live page, enough to represent the full problem

Comment: I am basically asking: How to make this more efficient: https://jsfiddle.net/0ey8p3p9/

Comment: doesn't appear you even tried to implement my suggestion

Comment: just take out the `_typeofcontent-cg` in selector

Comment: can also use `filter()` and test classes inside that

Comment: I tried your suggestion but not in the Fiddle. The 2nd fiddle was from a old file where I was started with putting every input in a single line but that became tidious real quickly so I started looking for a better way. I tried your code in the fiddle but not working so can you check what I do wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/tdo9go2q/2/

Comment: Sure...if you put them together and show it to me. Not here to do all the work for you.

Comment: Still not clear to me what the logic should be in the select

Comment: Can we go to chat? And I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tdo9go2q/3/

I think the logic becomes clear with this fiddle. When in the fiddle by the select: default is on then you should only see `hello` when 3dperspective is selected you should only see `bye` and I need to achieve this without adding a line of code for every div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135194/discussion-between-purple11111-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit convoluted so I focused on the what you want part.

Assuming you don't have much control over the classes that Joomla throws in there, no matter what you're going to need to build a way to capture the parent class and the child sub string you're looking for. But assuming you have both of those, you can make the show hide a bit generic. You can always tell jQ to look for children with a substring within a parent.

```
$("[class*='"+searchclass+"']",parent)
```

A fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/dvdxt58f/1/

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is the one suggested by charlietfl but there is another way to solve it.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#jform_params_theme_selection').bind('change', function (e) {
      if( $('#jform_params_theme_selection').val() == 'notheme') {
      } else if( $('#jform_params_theme_selection').val() == 'default') {

        $( ".subform-repeatable-group div[class*='__threed_']" ).hide();
        $( ".subform-repeatable-group div[class*='__dc_']" ).show();        

      } else if( $('#jform_params_theme_selection').val() == '3dperspective') {

        $( ".subform-repeatable-group div[class*='__threed_']" ).show();
        $( ".subform-repeatable-group div[class*='__dc_']" ).hide();        

      }
    }).trigger('change');

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Basically you use the `*` selector and with that you create:

`$( ".subform-repeatable-group div[class*='__threed_']" ).hide();`

I added this one as it might be useful in some occasions even when I go with charlietfl's answer.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tdo9go2q/11/